# Using other methods in `show`/`index` page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `show` action in a chair controller creates an acronym from a `Chair`'s name. The following codes works:

```
def show
  @chair = Chair.find(params[:id])
  @user = @chair.user
  first_letters = []
  @chair.name.split.each do |word|
    first_letters << word[0]
  end
  @names = first_letters.join
end
```

I want to extract an `acronym` method that takes care of creating the acronym. I tried this:

```
def show
  @chair = Chair.find(params[:id])
  @user = @chair.user
  @names = @chair.acronym
end

def acronym
  first_letters = []
  @chair.name.split.each do |word|
    first_letters << word[0]
  end
  first_letters.join
end
```

However, `acronym` couldn't be accessed from `show`. The method names and the views need to match, but is there a way to have a separate method `acronym` like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for `@chair.acronym` to work you need to define the `acronym` method on the `Chair` model.

Alternatively, you can also refactor like this, keeping the `acronym` method in your controller:

```
def acronym(chair)
  first_letters = []

  chair.name.split.each do |word|
    first_letters << word[0]
  end

  first_letters.join
end
```

You would call this method like this:

```
@names = acronym(@chair)
```

There are a few other options you have (decorators/presenters) outside the scope of this question (but may be worth investigating if you're interested in design/application structure)

If you move it into the Chair model in `chair.rb`, you can write it as:

```
def acronym
  first_letters = []

  name.split.each do |word|
    first_letters << word[0]
  end

  first_letters.join

  # Alternative, one line
  # name.split.map(&:chars).map(&:first).join('')
end
```

Then in your controller you can call `@chair.acronym`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im just curious as, i put `@chair.acronym` in the controller and also in the view. however I then deleted `@chair.acronym` from the controller to see what would happen, and it still worked. is this because all the information that the view needed was in the model, and not the controller?

Comment: @b.herring, yes, that's exactly what happened, if you put the `acronym` method inside the `app/models/chair.rb` file. That method becomes available on _any_ instance of chair you've instantiated, _anywhere_ inside of your application (other models, controllers, views, helpers, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The Rails way is supposed to put the business logic to in the Model file. 
We should put the `acronym` method logic in our model file and define it as instance method.

Then call  `acronym` method from the controller with `@chair` object as:

```
@chair.acronym
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to setup acronym as a new action on your controller you'll need to update your `config/routes.rb`. The simplest way would be to just add a static route:

```
get 'my_controller_name/acronym'
```

You'll also need a corresponding view to render your result in `app/views/my_controller/acronym.erb`

If you just want to play around without having to implement a view, you can just [render text](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text) from your action without using a template (view). Just add this to the end of your `acronym` action:

```
render plain: first_letters.join
```

Everything you want to know is in the [rails guide on routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: The question was not well stated, and I think you mistook the OP's intention.